# How to delete cakephp cached file by name or by name prefix?

Tags: php, cakephp, caching, cakephp-2.0

In cakephp 2.0 I cache some information getting from some service calls in file for individual users. Using individual user_id as a prefix of the cached file name, I cache the files under a custom cache configuration which saves in a folder under **cache** folder.

Like, if the service name is **get_user_info** and the custom cache folder name is **user_info** then for a user say user_id:111, a file will be cached with name **111_get_user_info** in **cache/user_info**.

If I need to remove the cached info for this user:111, I can't make that. Because **Cache::clear(false, 'user_info')** deletes all the cached files under **cache/user_info** and as a consequence other users cached info has removed as well.

Can anybody suggest me how can I clear the cached file by using a prefix match?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Any reason `delete` wouldn't work?

```
Cache::delete($key);
```

?

ref: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/caching.html#CacheEngine::delete

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `clearCache($file)` where $file need to be some like that:

```
$file = "myprefix_the_complete_name_with_extension.php";
```

you need to create the entire path to pass a cake.

keep me posted if this solution work for you.

Best Regards.